# Binding Image-Source to position of piece C#

Tags: c#, wpf, image, visual-studio, binding

**Situation:** I'am developing a chess game where the user can move the pieces on the board.
The board contains 8x8 fields (=64) just like a normal one.

---

**The board:** The board is a dynamically created Grid with 8 rows and 8 columns. Each "field" contains another Grid that contains a Rectangle (=the color of the field using the fill property) and an Image (=the image of the piece on the field [piece or empty]).

---

**What I want to do:** I want to bind the source property of the images to the position of any piece.

---

**Example:** When the position of any piece changes, the image automatically removes the old source (because the piece moved away) & the field where the piece is located now, updates the image source.
To be clear: I have a pawn at (1,1)||(A,1) and move it to (1,2)||(A,2). Now the image-source of the old position (1,1)||(A,1) should be set to empty because the piece moved, and the image-soruce of the new position-field should be set to "pawn.png".

---

**How it works now:** At the moment I have a click event on the image. When a first click event is registered, I save the clicked image (=ref) and wait for a second click. When a second click is registered, I set the source of the second clicked image equals the source of the first clicked image and the source of the first clicked image to an empty source... But this isn't a good solution...

---

**Question:** How can I do a binding to the 64 image-sources so that every position change of the 32 pieces gets notified to the UI?

---

Here the class **ChessField**:

---

```
    public class ChessField : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int X { get; protected set; }
    public int Y { get; protected set; }

    public bool Recheable
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    private readonly SolidColorBrush _defaultFieldColor;

    public ChessField(int X, int Y, SolidColorBrush fieldColor)
    {
        this.X = X;
        this.Y = Y;
        ColorProperty = fieldColor;
        _defaultFieldColor = fieldColor;            
        Recheable = false;
    }

    public void SetToDefault()
    {
        ColorProperty = _defaultFieldColor;
        Recheable = false;
    }

    private SolidColorBrush colorProperty;

    public SolidColorBrush ColorProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return colorProperty;
        }

        set
        {
            if (colorProperty == value) return;

            colorProperty = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }       


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

---

**PiecePos** is a struct and looks like this:

---

```
public struct PiecePos
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }

    public PiecePos(int X, int Y)
    {
        this.X = X;
        this.Y = Y;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (!(obj is PiecePos))
        {
            return false;
        }

        PiecePos toCompare = (PiecePos)obj;
        return (this.X == toCompare.X) && (this.Y == toCompare.Y);
    }
}
```

---

[image: The UI]

---

***Any help would be appreciated ! Thanks***

Comment: Your question is more like how you should build your program than a WPF specific question.

Comment: My program is already built and running. The question is: How can I do the binding for 64 images so that any position change of my pieces gets notified to the UI?... Hope this helps

Comment: Extend your `Piece` with an `ImageSource` property and bind it to the UI (as you already did it with the `EPieceColor`).

Comment: But the Color is always the same for the field. The image I want to bind, changes... Am I missing something? The image obj doesn't change, just the source...

Comment: It seems to me, that you could help your self by separating the field objects from the piece objects. In stead of letting a field object contain a piece object or not, then let a piece object have a position on the board, and make it possible to change the position of a piece object. Then you later on can make it possible to move a piece on the board using the mouse (by using the dragStarted, DragDelta and DragCompleted events)

Comment: @AndersHyldahl I like your point. Thank you !! (I already solved the problem and will post a solution later, just in case you are interested on how I solved it)

Comment: @AdrianEfford - It is good that you solved your problem. Also that you find my thoughts useful. And I would like to see how you solved your problem

Comment: @AndersHyldahl I posted the solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some work I solved the problem...

**Solution:**

1. Add a ImageSource property to the ChessField-Class
2. Add a default value to the ChessField-Class constructor
3. Do the binding where you dynamically create the Images

---

The **ChessField** should look like this:

```
public class ChessField : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int X { get; protected set; }
    public int Y { get; protected set; }

    public bool Recheable
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    private readonly SolidColorBrush _defaultFieldColor;

    public ChessField(int X, int Y, SolidColorBrush fieldColor, ImageSource imageSource)
    {
        this.X = X;
        this.Y = Y;
        ColorProperty = fieldColor;
        _defaultFieldColor = fieldColor;
        this.ImageSource = imageSource;
        Recheable = false;
    }

    public void SetToDefault()
    {
        ColorProperty = _defaultFieldColor;
        Recheable = false;
    }

    private SolidColorBrush colorProperty;

    public SolidColorBrush ColorProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return colorProperty;
        }

        set
        {
            if (colorProperty == value) return;

            colorProperty = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private ImageSource imageSource;

    public ImageSource ImageSource
    {
        get { return imageSource; }
        set
        {
            if (imageSource == value) return;

            imageSource = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

---

Here how to dynamically create the Images and add them to the UI:

```
private void CreateImages()
    {
        ChessField chessField = new ChessField(X, Y, defaultColor, startImage); //Create field

        //Each field is a single grid
        Grid fieldGrid = new Grid();
        fieldGrid.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, Helper.BoardSize - Y);
        fieldGrid.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, X - 1);

        Image imageField = new Image();
        imageField.MouseDown += ImageClickEvent; //Click event
        imageField.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
        imageField.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
        imageField.Tag = x + "," + y; //Set the image tag (needed for the click event)

        imageField.DataContext = chessField;
        imageField.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, "ImageSource"); //Binding

        _chessFields.Add(chessField); //Add to list --> so we can access the field on the click event

        fieldGrid.Children.Add(imageField);
        BoardGrid.Children.Add(fieldGrid); //Add field-grid to the main-grid in the XAML
    }
```

---

Image click event:

```
private void ImageClickEvent()
    {
        //Move to
        var pieceToMove = Board.PiecesOnTheBoard
            .FirstOrDefault(piece => piece.Position.X == _lastSelectedField.X && piece.Position.Y == _lastSelectedField.Y && piece.IsAlive);

        var oldField = _chessFields.FirstOrDefault(field =>
            field.X == pieceToMove.Position.X && field.Y == pieceToMove.Position.Y);

        pieceToMove?.Move(new PiecePos(clickedChessField.X, clickedChessField.Y)); //Move

        var newField = _chessFields.FirstOrDefault(field =>
            field.X == pieceToMove?.Position.X && field.Y == pieceToMove.Position.Y);


        if (oldField != null)
        {
            oldField.ImageSource = Helper.EmptyImage; //Use binding to change image
        }

        if (newField != null)
        {
            newField.ImageSource = pieceToMove?.GetImage(); //Use binding to change image
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nice :) - You solved your problem as you have planned to do. Good job. But still I think you should think in objects and how they interact :)